# How to check if an embedded document exists in database before saving in Mongoose

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, mongoose, passport.js

I'm making a basic authentication system using Express, Mongoose and PassportJS.
What I want to do is to check the database if the entered username and password already exist in the database. Here's my sample code below:

```
//Post: /signup
app.post('/signup', function (req, res) {
  var username = req.body.person.user.username;
  var password = req.body.person.user.password;

  Person.user.find({'username': username}, function (err, user) {
    if (err) {
      console.log(err.name);
    } else {
      console.log('User Found');
    }
  });
});
```

The problem is it returns this kind of error:

```
TypeError: Cannot call method 'find' of undefined
```

Could someone please help me.

Comment: error says that Person.user is undefined ... first initialize an object , than call methods on it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As robertklep pointed, you are not checking correctly for an user's existence. Also, since username is most likely unique, you can just use findOne (findOne() returns a single object while find() may also return a single object but will wrap it in an array).

```
Person.findOne({'username': username}, function (err, user) {
  if (err) {
     console.log(err.name);
     return;
  }
  if (!user)
    console.log('User not Found');
    return;
  }
  console.log('User found');

});
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for this:

```
Person.find({ 'user.username' : username }, ...)
```

FWIW, if the callback isn't called with an error it doesn't mean a user was found, it just means that there were no errors performing the query. But `user` can still be null, meaning that the query didn't have any matching results.

Comment: I tried that method but the problem is it returns the following error: TypeError: Object { first: 'Miguel',
  last: 'Lorenzo',
  _id: 515e3c2d99ebf01706000020,
  __v: 0,
  user: { username: 'MIGO123', password: '123', enable: true },
  siblings: [],
  employments: [],
  educations: [],
  mother: { affiliate: false },
  father: { affiliate: false },
  address: {},
  contact: {} } has no method 'find'

Comment: What is `Person`? It seems you're overwriting your model class with a result. Could you add your schema to your question as well?